# Tbb concurrent hash map iterator

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, tbb

I'm traversing an entire tbb concurrent hash map using an iterator and inspecting each (key,value) pair.

```
for (MAP::pair = myHashTable.begin(); myHashTable.end(); pair++)
```

How can I parallelize this iterator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `range()` method which is described in the [Reference Manual](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_hash_map_cls/parallel_iteration_container.htm):

```
HashTable_t myHashTable; // assuming HashTable_t is concurrent_hash_map specialization
tbb::parallel_for( myHashTable.range(), [](const HashTable_t::range_type &r) {
    for( HashTable_t::iterator i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); i++);
} );
```

(I use [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) for concision but show the types explicitly for sake of [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03))

And please pay attention to the caution note there:

> Do not call concurrent operations, including count and find while iterating the table. Use concurrent_unordered_map if concurrent traversal and insertion are required.

Comment: Can you please add an example. So e.g. you implement the ()-operator but what do one have to fill in then? void operator()( const tbb::blocked_range<tbb::concurrent_map<t,t>::iterator> range ) const {

Comment: Thank you! Didn't get it to write HashTable_t::range_type.